# How many sequences of 2n coin flips have exactly n heads and n tails

Tags: combinatorics

hi this sound like a tricky question for me.

How many sequences of 2n coin flips have exactly n heads and n tails.
my first impression is that the answer should be (2n choose n) * (2n choose n).

but the question is similar to say 
How many sequences of 2n coin flips have exactly n heads?
because for 2n size, if you flip the coin 2n times and get n heads, it will always result in n tails right?
so the correct answer should be (2n choose n) only
is that right?

Comment: Yup, it's just $$\color{red}{2n\choose n}$$

Comment: I thought so, thanks!

Comment: Be careful as you type things to keep naming schemes consistent.  You wrote in your attempted answer "2n choose **m**" instead of "2n choose **n**."

Comment: true lol, thanks1

Comment: You can obtain $\binom{n}{k}$ by typing `$\binom{n}{k}$`.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @ Taussig thanks I will need that, as a matter of fact looking at it now